# Can't resize Ubuntu Partition inside VMware

Tags: linux, partition, partition-alignment

I had a 30 GB machine and I run out space. Then, via the VMWare Workstation GUI, I have extended that space.

It got to "unallocated space" at first, then I tried to extend it with `gparted`, but no luck, there is not option to resize it.

https://pasteboard.co/JUfr2G7.png

Then, I have tried this:

https://www.joomlaworks.net/blog/item/168-resizing-the-disk-space-on-ubuntu-server-vms-running-on-vmware-esxi-5

But I got no output from:

```
vgdisplay
```

So I cannot extend it.

I have tried manually to do:

```
pvcreate -ff /dev/sda3
vgcreate "name" /dev/sda3
vgextend name /dev/sda3
```

but got:

```
  Physical volume '/dev/sda3' is already in volume group 'name'
  Unable to add physical volume '/dev/sda3' to volume group 'name'
  /dev/sda3: physical volume not initialized.
```

Seems like a rathole =/

Answer (score 0):

I solved it via de 1 method:

```
cd /mnt/
ls
mount /dev/sda3 /mnt/
cd /mnt/
rm -rf lost+found/
cp -rp /home/* /mnt/
mv /home/ /home.orig
mkdir /home
cd /
umount /dev/sda3
mount /dev/sda3 /home/
df /dev/sda3
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Filesystem     1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda3       51342396 7936608  40767968  17% /home
------------------------------------------------------------------------
cp /etc/fstab /etc/fstab.orig
nano /etc/fstab
```

Added this line to fstab:

/dev/sda3   /home   ext4    defaults    0   0

```
rm -r /home.orig

df -u
```

The result is:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            3.4G     0  3.4G   0% /dev
tmpfs           689M  1.8M  688M   1% /run
/dev/sda5        29G   19G  9.1G  68% /
tmpfs           3.4G     0  3.4G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           3.4G     0  3.4G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop1      219M  219M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/66
/dev/loop3       33M   33M     0 100% /snap/snapd/11107
/dev/loop2       65M   65M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1514
/dev/loop0       56M   56M     0 100% /snap/core18/1988
/dev/loop4       33M   33M     0 100% /snap/snapd/11402
/dev/loop5       52M   52M     0 100% /snap/snap-store/518
/dev/sda3        49G  7.6G   39G  17% /home
/dev/sda1       511M  4.0K  511M   1% /boot/efi
tmpfs           689M   20K  689M   1% /run/user/1000
```

Clean and sleek